# number of points of tangency of the zero divergence vector field and the equator of the sphere.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $V$ be vector field on the sphere $S^2$ and $\operatorname{div} V=0$. What is the minimum number tangency points of this vector field and the equator of the sphere?

Comment: @John I even don't know how to begin to solve this problem. $div V=0$ is a local condition, but the statement is global. I think that there should be some trick.

Comment: Hint: divergence theorem.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I know divergence theorem only for $\mathbb R^3$. $$\int \int \int \operatorname{div} F dV= \int \int F*n dS.$$ where $S$ is boundary of $V$. Am I correct that in the case of $S^2$ this theorem says that $$\int \int \operatorname{div} F dV= \int F*n dS.$$ where $V$ is $1$ dimensional submanifold  and $S$ is its boundary? Then the problem is easy, let $V={(x,y,z)|x>=0}$, $S=S^1$. $int F*n dS=0$ then F*n has at least $2$ zeroes.

Comment: @user152187: that's correct (except V should be a 2-dimensional region rather than a 1-dimensional submanifold)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on comments: at the non-tangency points, the field flows either out of Northern hemisphere or into it. Since the divergence is zero, both of these must occur. This implies the existence of at least two points of tangency to the equator, since they must separate the equator arcs  where the flow is inward from the arcs where it is outward.

However, this is not the end of solution. If you are going to answer the question "What is the minimum number..?" with "2", you  better have a proof that 2 can be attained.  Fortunately, a constructive proof is easy. Consider the velocity of the [Terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_%28solar%29): it is described by the flow that goes west at every point, rotating around the globe in 24 hours. Turn this picture sideways, so that the stationary point are on the equator. (Equivalently, turn the equator so that it becomes the union of $0 ^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ meridians.)